# First N largest elements from matrix with constraints - matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am having a trouble with coding in matrix.

I have a matrix `P` with `n x m` dimensions.

I need to find the first largest `N` (less than n) elements from the `P` and flag them to `1`.

Let the matrix be `Y`, where `Y(i,j)=1 or 0`

Constraint :   `max(sum(Y(i))=1 ;  min(sum(Y(i))=0`

Application - I have n number of customers list and m number of offers. `P(i,j)` is expected profit from i th customer with j th offer. I need to figure out a matrix `Y (n x m)` which gives me the maximum expected profit.
Each customers can get maximum 1 offer (or 0) and there is a budget so that we can only make `N` offers.

Comment: I have an idea. I think all the elements can be ranked by the largest number, after indexing them. Then perhaps give the index=1 whenever the i was never flagged and N has not been reached. But it's just my idea. Help please!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with `max(sum(Y(i))=1 ; min(sum(Y(i))=0` ? If Y=0 or 1, then sum(Y)>1 if any Y==1.

Comment: for each row/customer can only get at most 1 offer :)

Comment: If each row in your matrix is a customer and you can only make 1 offer per customer, you can start by rejecting all but the largest value in each row. Right?

Comment: @tmpearce : no! I did this and it's incorrect, see my answer. The problem appears to be an instance of the stable matching problem, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem

Comment: If that is true, the OP hasn't provided enough information because it isn't actually contained anywhere in the question what the true constraints are.